# Ruby - How to use an array value as the key in a hash lookup

Tags: ruby

I am trying to output a string text in which I use a value from a hash (lookup). The hash key is in the input array.

The desired outcome would be "Hello John" but the approach I am taking is not working. Any suggestions to correct this?

```
input = [44,55]
lookup = { 44 => "Dave", 55 => "John" }
puts "Hello #{lookup[input[1]]}"
```

Comment: Solved! I made a typo in my original code and lost an hour staring at it. The solution I proposed in this post is actually working.

I will close this question in 7 minutes (soonest I can close it). Apologies for using up your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works for me in `irb`

```
2.2-head :001 > input = [44,55]
 => [44, 55]
2.2-head :002 > lookup = { 44 => "Dave", 55 => "John" }
 => {44=>"Dave", 55=>"John"}
2.2-head :003 > puts "Hello #{lookup[input[1]]}"
Hello John
```

To iterate through your keys, use this:

```
input.each do |key|
  puts "Hello #{lookup[key]}"
end

=> Hello Dave
=> Hello John
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not working?

```
irb(main):001:0> input = [44,55]
=> [44, 55]
irb(main):002:0> lookup = { 44 => "Dave", 55 => "John" }
=> {44=>"Dave", 55=>"John"}
irb(main):003:0> puts "Hello #{lookup[input[1]]}"
Hello John
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quotation marks printed use [`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p):

```
input = [44,55]
lookup = { 44 => "Dave", 55 => "John" }
p "Hello #{lookup[input[1]]}" #=> "Hello John"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this then, to delimiter a method parameter you need () or nothing, not []

```
def lookup key
  hash = { 44 => "Dave", 55 => "John" }
  hash[key]
end

input = [44, 55]
puts "Hello #{lookup(input[1])}"
```

or did you mean this

```
lookup = { 44 => "Dave", 55 => "John" }
puts "Hello #{lookup[input[1]]}"
```